# C# : Using SendKeys to "press" button in another app works until patrent app closes

Tags: c#

I am writing a c# Console app that looks to see if another application is running, and if so, close it and re-launch it.
This part works fine.
The app being opened then needs the "start" button being pressed. This button is pre-selected when the app opens, it just needs pressing.
Hitting the space bar also "presses" the button (Enter key does not).

I've used `SendKeys.SendWait(" ")` to simulate the space bar being pressed. Works fine....until the parent app (I.e.: my Console app) then closes. At this point the Child app (i.e.: the open my program opens) reverts back to waiting for the start button to be press (almost like my program presses the "stop" button before exiting).

my code is

```
 Process[] runningProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcess");
        String appName = "MyProcess.exe";
        int liMilliseconds = 5000;'

 try
        {
            if (runningProcesses.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (Process process in runningProcesses)
                {
                    process.Kill();                                                  

                    for (int a = 30; a >= 0; a--)                                   
                    {
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                        Console.Write("Re-launching MyProcess in {0} seconds.", a);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                    Process.Start(appName);                                         
                    Thread.Sleep(liMilliseconds);                                    
                    SendKeys.SendWait(" ");                                         
                }
            }
            else
                Process.Start(appName);                                             
                Thread.Sleep(liMilliseconds);
                SendKeys.SendWait(" ");
        }

        catch (Exception msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nOh Snap, there has been an error. Message reads : \n\n" + msg);
            Console.Read();
        }`
```

can someone point out my error, and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What is your problem? It's normal that your console application is doing nothing when it's closed, because it's not executed anymore.

Comment: how another program acts is entirely down to it.. you sent a space to it if your app closes nothing more will  happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now I just find one error in your code. Your `else` has no brackets, so `Thread.Sleep` and `SendKeys.SendWait` is executed at the end of your program.

To fix this. add brackets to the `else`.

```
Process[] runningProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcess");
String appName = "MyProcess.exe";
int liMilliseconds = 5000;

try
{
    if (runningProcesses.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (Process process in runningProcesses)
        {
            process.Kill();                                                  

            for (int a = 30; a >= 0; a--)                                   
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                Console.Write("Re-launching MyProcess in {0} seconds.", a);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Process.Start(appName);                                         
            Thread.Sleep(liMilliseconds);                                    
            SendKeys.SendWait(" ");                                         
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Process.Start(appName);                                             
        Thread.Sleep(liMilliseconds);
        SendKeys.SendWait(" ");
    }
}
catch (Exception msg)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nOh Snap, there has been an error. Message reads : \n\n" + msg);
    Console.Read();
}
```